# How to specify the redis configuration file in installation?

Tags: windows, redis

(On Windows)

I know that I can instal redis through:

`./redis-server --service-install --service-name myredis`

But this will use the default configuration. I want something that allow me to specify the .conf file in installatio process. Something like:

`./redis-server --service-install --service-name myredis --config-file my-config.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty old, and you probably already found your answer, but I figured I'd share what I found for those googling it.

You can specify a config file by doing the following `redis-server --service-install my-config.conf` and then you can verify that the start up parameters now include your config file.